# Accepting a non fixed length group of parameters in a function

Tags: c#, methods

So what I'm trying to do is build a logging function, I'm hoping to get it taking the format

```
public static void AddToLog(Guid someID, LogArea myLogger, string message, object object1, object object2... ... ...);
```

The second to last parameter I'd like to accept a string which is in the format of something akin to string.format and the last X parameters would be the objects to replace with the string format with.

I'm having a hard time because I can't remember what the programming concept is called to search for to find examples of this in C#. I also realise there's fantastic logging packages out there - I just need this to do something special that's why I'm re-inventing the wheel :D

Could any suggest how to tell C# not to expect a fixed length of parameters? (and for bonus points if anyone knows how to best document this in the `///` notation I'd really appreciate it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [`params[]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx).

```
public static void AddToLog(Guid someID, LogArea myLogger, string message, params object[] list)
{
    // you can use it like an array
    Console.WriteLine("Guid:{0} Message:{1} Objects:{2}"
        , someID, message, string.Join(",", list));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
public static void AddToLog(
    Guid someID, LogArea myLogger, string message, params object[] parameters)
{
    foreach(object p in parameters)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the keyword you're looking for is `params`

```
public static void AddToLog(Guid someID, LogArea myLogger, string message, params object[] objects)
```